# How to apply something like `lxml.etree` to RDD in Python?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, pyspark, rdd

I am a beginner of using spark and not very familiar with handling XML parsing. Now I have a RDD named `data`, which contains Gzipped XML with the following format:

```
<row Body="xxxxxxxx" CommentCount="0"  
CreationDate="2008-10-12T20:26:29.397" Id="195995" 
LastActivityDate="2008-10-12T20:26:29.397" OwnerDisplayName="Eric
Wendelin" OwnerUserId="25066" ParentId="195973" PostTypeId="2" 
Score="0" />
```

But some rows are split across multiple lines and some XML are incorrectly formatted.

Then how can I handle XML parsing like `lxml.etree` to get all the valid rows that start with `<row` and has a similar format as the example above?

Thank you very much.